# SharePoint 2013 - different term sets for navigations

Tags: term-store, managed-navigation

Is it possible to use different term sets - one for current navigation (left side) and second for global navigation (top). By default under settings -> navigation I can choose only one term set, so both navigation menus are bounded.

I have done some corrections in masterpage DelegateControl and ContentPlaceHolder tags for for customization purpose, but haven't found a way to change desired term set.

Is that even possible? If yes, how?

Comment: In the term tree control can't you see "Global Navigation" and "Local Navigation" folders?

Comment: @AmalHashim I don't want to use Structured navigation. Instead - for both navigations (Global and Current)  I want to use Managed navigation type, but for each navigation - different term set!

Comment: Not sure if you can use two completely different term sets. But under the navigation tab you can check "Visibility in menus" and select which terms are visible in each.

Comment: @Rothrock It is clear, that this is not a standart SharePoint feature, that can be configured through GUI. And as I mentioned before - it is possible to choose terms, but identical for both navigations (through GUI). I am interested in finding a way to use different term sets separately for each navigation.

Comment: Make a third term set that is your navigation set, pin/reuse the others into it, select which appear where.

Comment: @Kristaps Vilerts, would be interested to know if you ever found a solution for this. I'm looking for one as well.

Comment: @evanmcd Unfortunately I did'nt found a legit solution to this problem, but got "workaround" - for _global navigation_ I used different attribute - __ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource"__ and added values manually.